# Why is not the Gitlab Junit Attachment feature working

Tags: gitlab

I'm trying to get the Gitlab [JUnit Screenshots](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/testing/unit_test_reports.html#view-junit-screenshots-on-gitlab) feature to function. Right now I'm handcrafting my XML just to test the feature but I can't get it to work.

It says the screenshot support was introduced in v13.0 of Gitlab. We're currently running on gitlab.com which reports this version 16.2 on the help page: "GitLab Enterprise Edition 16.2.0-pre b442d76a3c7"

In fact, Gitlab doesn't seem to parse the `<system-out>` tag at all so this is my first focus. Then I'll move on to "ATTACHMENT" data (although I tried that first). Whatever I put in the `<failure>` tag on the other hand, is presented as "System out" in the UI. What's up?

I have the following Junit report XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<testsuite name="MySuite" tests="1" failures="1" errors="0" skipped="0" time="9.152" timestamp="2023-07-06T10:40:18" hostname="localhost">
    <testcase classname="MyClass" name="failingTest" time="1.014">
        <failure>Failure text</failure>
        <system-out>System-out text</system-out>
    </testcase>
</testsuite>
```

This is the UI produced:
[image: Gitlab UI produced from the XML parsed]

Comment: there are no attachment tag in your Junit file